# Android camera preview callback buffer not filled: is always full of zeros

Tags: java, android, android-camera

While `Camera.PreviewCallback#onPreviewFrame` does get called, the passed `byte[]` buffer is not populated by the camera: it is always full of zeros.

The reason why I'm using the deprecated API is that I was getting a very low framerate using the newer one. Since my cameras are considered `LEGACY`, I was recommended to try the deprecated API.

My code, where the callback does get called, but the buffer is empty:

```
camera = Camera.open();
camera.setParameters(configurator.getParameters());
Size size = configurator.getOutputSize();
camera.addCallbackBuffer(new byte[size.getWidth() * size.getHeight() * ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(ImageFormat.YV12) / 8]);
camera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(this);
camera.startPreview();
```

One weird thing I see in the log is the following: when I call `camera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(this);`, this debug message appears: `D/Camera-JNI: (tid:3466)[release camera] - X context=0x0`.
Also, all modifications to the buffer are cleared: the buffer is actually being filled with zeros before each call to the callback.

Comment: What device? Does the stock camera app work? Are you sure the camera is viewing a substantially non-black scene? Does your code work as you expect in the emulator?

Comment: Pointing the camera directly at a light source does work. I guess my exposure settings are incorrect, to say the least. Thank you for your help!

Comment: For the record: it wasn't actually my exposure settings, it was the FPS range I specified: the max. FPS range didn't leave enough exposure time.

Comment: Interesting, you should put that as the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the lack of light compared to the exposure time: I have set my preview FPS range to the maximum one, but this caused the exposure time to be too low compared to the lighting in my room. The result was a pitch black image, except when I pointed the camera directly at a light source. Changing the FPS range to a lower one fixed my issue.